# Skip the first value of column range and add to a list

Tags: c#, excel

SO I have a range that I loop through and then add the values to a list. I want to skip the first value because it is a header. How Could I go about doing that? AS it stands I am adding all the value

```
    {
        var cellValues = new List<string>();
        //var rowsCount = worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
        var columnRange = worksheet.UsedRange.Columns[1];

        foreach (var item in columnRange)
        {
            foreach (var cellValue in item.Value)
            {

                cellValues.Add(cellValue.ToString());

            }
        }

        return cellValues;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `for` loop instead of `foreach`:

```
    for (int a = 1; a < columnRange.Count; a++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < columnRange[a].Value.Count; b++)
        {
            cellValues.Add(columnRange[a].Value[b].ToString());

        }
    }
```

or

```
        var cellValues = new List<string>();
        //var rowsCount = worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
        var columnRange = worksheet.UsedRange.Columns[1];
        bool first = true;
        foreach (var item in columnRange)
        {
            if (first)
            {
                first = false;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var cellValue in item.Value)
                {    
                    cellValues.Add(cellValue.ToString());    
                }
            }
        }

        return cellValues;
```

or `Skip()` as mentioned by ramin.

Comment: @Roma the first and second run fine but give me no values in the list. .

Comment: are there values in columnRange after var columnRange = worksheet.UsedRange.Columns[1]; ?

Comment: @Roma yes there is

Comment: i,ve edited for loop, but second variant must work. Have you checked if there are values after second variant?

Comment: @Roma using break points it runs through the if statement and then stops the process and returns zero values.

Comment: @Roma It gives me the same result zero items returned.

Comment: @Roma I added the if statement to the second foreach and got a correct result thank you.

Comment: @EthanF., misunderstanding, i thougt that you don't want first item in column range, not in columnRange.Value. You are welcome)

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ's `Skip` function.

```
    var cellValues = new List<string>();
    //var rowsCount = worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
    var columnRange = worksheet.UsedRange.Columns[1];

    foreach (var item in columnRange)
    {
        foreach (var cellValue in ((object[,])item.Value).Cast<object>().Skip(1))
        {

            cellValues.Add(cellValue.ToString());

        }
    }

    return cellValues;
```

But because `item.Value` is a dynamic type, we need to cast it in order to use an extension method, and because it's a jagged array we need to use `Cast<object>()`.

Comment: Hey so when i tried this I get the error An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code.

Comment: ah, it's because it's a dynamic type, so needs to be casted first. I can update the answer.